# Keras: Concatenating metadata into a CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a CNN that is trained with images. I also obtained the geometry (68x2 - 68 points with x, y coordinates) of the face. I want to encode the geometry after all the convolution layers and use them in the fully connected layers. I'm using vggFace model.

```
'''
Load the model
'''
vgg_model = VGGFace(
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))


'''
Customize the model
'''
# Add geometry input
geo_input = Input(shape=(1,136,1))
geo_input = Flatten(name='flatten')(geo_input)


last_layer = vgg_model.get_layer('pool5').output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
x = concatenate([x, geo_input], axis=1)
x = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='relu', name='fc6')(x)
x = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='relu', name='fc7')(x)
out = Dense(nb_class, activation='softmax', name='fc8')(x)

custom_vgg_model = Model(
    [vgg_model.input, geo_input], 
    out)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects. Received inputs: [<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'flatten/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>]. Input 1 (0-based) originates from layer type `Flatten`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
# Add geometry input
geo_input = Input(shape=(1,136,1))
geo_input = Flatten(name='flatten')(geo_input)
```

In the second line, `geo_input` is not an input anymore. It's an output of the `Flatten` layer. You're passing this to the `Model` creation. So you need to keep the correct input tensor:

```
geo_input_tensor = Input(shape=(1,136,1))
geo_input = Flatten(name='flatten')(geo_input_tensor)

.....
......

custom_vgg_model = Model([vgg_model.input, geo_input_tensor], out)
```